# Should I reset all values?

Tags: c++

I was taught to "reset" all values to 0 when I free a struct, is that something I should keep on doing or is it a waste?

I will usually do something like:

```
example->a = 0;
delete example;
```

I haven't seen a problem when running it but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: you've deleted it, why do you care what value the garbage has?

Comment: The only reason to do that is to hide a bug longer.

Comment: Whoever taught you that does not really understand C++. There may or may not be valid reasons for doing that in very specific situations, but blindly doing this all the time accomplishes absolutely nothing useful, whatsoever. Additionally, there's a reasonable chance that your C++ compiler simply ignores this silliness and doesn't even compile it, without telling you.

Comment: I sometimes do `delete example;` and then `example = nullptr;` to make sure my program crashes when I would accidentally still use `example` afterwards. However a debugger should be able to catch a use after delete without doing this extra step.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is if you have a shortlived buffer with a password in cleartext. You may then want to overwrite the password with random garbage before releasing the memory.

Comment: `delete example` should invoke the destructor, and the destructor should do all the required cleanup of the fields of the object.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Then simply writing zeros wouldn't be enough: https://godbolt.org/z/rxP55dhK3

Comment: @Artyer No, I wanted random garbage - but [`memset_explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) lets you write one value into all positions. It'll come in C2x and I assume C++ will get it too eventually (if there isn't already a similar thing hidden in the standard library somewhere). :)

Comment: Programming is hard, why making it harder by trying to follow pointless rules? What benefit were you told this has? This attitude to programming is sometimes called [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: @john -- Re: "to make sure my program crashes" -- it might, or it might do something else; there are no requirements on what happens when you dereference a null pointer.

Comment: The reason you usually see a crash when accessing a null pointer is most processors have a no-man's land at address 0 and for the first few hundred or thousand addresses afterward specifically to catch null pointers. I've only seen a few systems that didn't have the address space to be wasteful for null pointer defense and thankfully never coded for one. I like me a tight constraints challenge, but not when I'm working.

Comment: *I was taught...*  By who?  Have you asked that person **why?**

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no point in doing that. Also, don't manage memory manually, put the objects on the stack, or use smart pointers if you have to put them on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

One motivation for resetting/overwriting values before releasing the memory can be found in

[N2897](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2897.htm) - `memset_explicit` - Project: ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG14: Programming Language C

> Abstract
>
> Sensitive data, like passwords or keying data, should be cleared from memory as soon as they are not needed. This requires ensuring the compiler will not optimize the memory overwrite away. This proposal adds a `memset_explicit` function that allows users to express that a memory area needs to be actually cleared.

So, it may be warranted in some very specific situations - but those are very rare and chances are that your compiler will optimize away your attempt at doing it manually anyway, so don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no point.

If an object will cease to exist, then its members will no longer exist.   Assigning the object members to zero (or to any other value for that matter) achieves nothing, as accessing them unavoidably causes undefined behaviour - whether they are zeroed out or not.

Practically, such approaches can cause buggy code to pass some (not all) test cases.   Advocates of the approach smugly point at such passed test cases.   The problem is, passing those test cases is an illusion - the code is still buggy and, almost invariably, symptoms of the bug will emerge at some point in the future as surrounding code evolves.   Often after the person writing the "zeroing out" code has left - and some other developer is left the unhappy task of finding and correcting the obscured bug.   That process is often difficult and unrewarding, since the bug has been obscured, and there after often other bugs exposed in the process that need to be found and fixed.

There are some limited circumstances where such approaches are useful (e.g. zeroing out memory that contains a password, so other programs can't scrub memory).   But those cases are much less common that advocates of the approach claim.

Personally (other than the very specialised cases where such approaches are appropriate) whenever I see someone advocating such an approach, I substantially downgrade my assessment of their competence as a developer.   And I have refused to employ such a person.